# Fourier transform of delta composed to a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I need your help! I would like to calculate the Fourier transform (or the Laplace transform) of
\begin{align*}
\delta(f(t))
\end{align*}
where I know the Fourier transform (or the Laplace transform) of $f$. The function $f$ is on $\mathbb{R}$. If you prefer, I'm looking for the Fourier transform of
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{1}(f(t)=0)
\end{align*}
Thanks to everybody, any suggestions are helpful

Comment: Use the property $\delta(f(t))=\sum_i \delta(t_i)/|f'(t_i)|$, where $t_i$ are the zeroes of $f(t)$.

Comment: maybe a change of variables $u=f(t)$ in the intergral transform is useful.

Comment: @RaadShaikh Are you sure that experesion is correct? there is no $t$ in the RHS

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I meant $\delta(t-t_i)$.

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function provides more insight.